# Cant find "States" tab in blend

Tags: blend, states

I don't know how but i cant find the tab "States". all am able to see is project, assets,device and parts.
I searched everywhere but unable to find an option to bring it back. My question is how to bring the States tab back?

my version for blend is 2013. Its was a part of visual studio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In menu strip .
Window -> States - check.